# LINQ groupby отсортировать в группе

Tags: c#, linq

Нужно сгруппировать все паллеты по сроку годности, отсортировать по возрастанию срока годности, в каждой группе отсортировать паллеты по весу.

```
class Pallete
{
    public List<Box> boxes { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? getExpirationDate() {
        return boxes.Min(b => b.ExpirationDate);
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return boxes.Sum(b => b.Weight) + 30;
    }
}
```

Получилось сгруппировать все паллеты по сроку годности, отсортировать по возрастанию срока годности. Как теперь в каждой группе отсортировать по весу?

```
private List<Pallete> palletes;

    public void getGroupedBy() {
        var g = palletes
            .GroupBy(p => p.getExpirationDate())
            .OrderBy(p => p.Key);

        foreach (var x in g)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("ExDate:{0}", x.Key);
            foreach (var y in x)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("=====weight:{0}, id:{1}", y.getWeight(), y.Id);
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
Сделал так

```
    public void getGroupedBy() {
        var g = palletes
            .GroupBy(p => p.getExpirationDate())
            .OrderBy(p => p.Key)
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.OrderBy(p => p.getWeight()))
            .GroupBy(p => p.Key);

        foreach (var x in g)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("ExDate:{0}", x.Key);
            foreach (var y in x)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("==ExDate:{0}", y.Key);
                foreach (var z in y.Value) {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("=====weight:{0}, id:{1}", z.getWeight(), z.Id);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

На мой взгляд кривовато. Можно как то улучшить результирующую структуру? Привести к IGrouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы выролняете `ToDictionary` и `GroupBy` почле сортировок, что может нарушить порядок ваших элементов. Операция сортировки должна быть последней для того, чтобы гарантировать эту сортировку. Наример

```
var g = palletes
    .GroupBy(p => p.getExpirationDate())
    .Select(x => new { x.Key, Items = x.OrderBy(z=>z.getExpirationDate()).ToArray() })
    .OrderBy(p => p.Key).ToArray();

foreach (var x in g)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("ExDate:{0}", x.Key);
    foreach (var y in x.Items)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("=====weight:{0}, id:{1}", y.getWeight(), y.Id);
    }
}
```

Если  надо обернуть в функцию

```
public Tuple<DateTime?, Pallete[]>[] Foo()
{
    var g = palletes
    .GroupBy(p => p.getExpirationDate())
    .Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.Key, x.OrderBy(z => z.getExpirationDate()).ToArray()))
    .OrderBy(p => p.Item1).ToArray();

    foreach (var x in g)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("ExDate:{0}", x.Item1);
        foreach (var y in x.Item2)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("=====weight:{0}, id:{1}", y.getWeight(), y.Id);
        }
    }       
    return g;
}
```

Comment: А как можно вернуть anonymous type из метода? Допустим я хочу оставить в методе только запрос и возвращать его значение, а уже дальше, что то с этим делать - пускать на вывод или записывать значения куда-то еще.

Comment: Сделал через IEnumerable<dynamic>

Comment: dynamic медленный, не используйте его без реальной необходимости. Обновил ответ.